# WINAPI Add user to directory

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, atl

I'm trying to add user with selected rights to directory. Unfortunately I have not yet found a way to do it. Maybe someone faced this task and will be able to help. Screenshots before and after.
[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: [GetSecurityInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-getsecurityinfo), update the respective descriptors as needed, [SetSecurityInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setsecurityinfo).

Comment: You could look at the command line utility `icacls` and shell out to that to do the heavy lifting.  That might be easier than trying to wrap your mind around the somewhat arcane Windows security APIs.